# Moving a JLabel's position for every update

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, repaint

I'm learning Swing and I have the following code:

```
public class SimView {

private JFrame frame;
private JLabel background;
private JPanel car_panel;

public SimView() {

    frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    background = new JLabel("");
    background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
            "C:\\Users\\D__\\Desktop\\background.png"));
    background.setBounds(0, 0, 384, 462);
    frame.getContentPane().add(background);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    car_panel = new JPanel();
    car_panel.setBounds(175, 430, 16, 21);
    car_panel.setVisible(true);
    car_panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    background.add(car_panel);

    MoveCarRunnable carMover = new MoveCarRunnable(car_panel);

}

private static class MoveCarRunnable implements Runnable {

    private JPanel car;

    MoveCarRunnable(final JPanel car) {

        this.car = car;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Should I call rePaint() on the car_panel here then ? 

    }

}
```

What I want to do is to move the JLabel called "car" 's y coordinates for every update to get the effect of it moving by itself i.e. no user interaction. I'm not quite sure how to do this, I suppose I need to have some sort of repaint() method redrawing the position of the JLabel for every update. But how do I get this class to know that it needs to update the position?

Any pointers (links/code) would be appreciated. I want to get the concept of how Swing and its components work in this case,  rather than just employing a solution but of course I am interested in a solution so I can study it closer. Thanks

**EDIT:**
Please see my edit code above

Comment: 1. Use a javax.swing.Timer to pace your updates 2. Use setLocation() to move your component 3. use label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize()) to size you label. 4. Using null-layout is no a very good choice to learn Swing, rather use LayoutManager's 5. If you want to see an animation, take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425220/painting-an-image-using-graphics2d/13426047#13426047)

Comment: @mKorbel pure coincincidence I guess, or the other poster was inspired from my example... impossible to know. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create a separate `Thread` that would modify the location of your label and then call `validate()` and `repaint()` on the container (`frame.getContentPane()`). Don't forget to put some `sleep()` value inside the thread.

However, there would be a better approach to create a separate `JPanel`. Inside it you would override the `paintComponent` method or the `paint` method and there you would draw an image instead of moving `JLabel`s around.

Comment: Can you kindly provide a short example showing what you mean? I have created another Thread but not sure how to repaint? It's not working for me. Please see my edit to what I have added so far.

Comment: Add this inside the run() method: label.setLocation(x, y); frame.getContentPane().validate(); frame.getContentPane().repaint();

Comment: Oops. Always forget that. But done that now. I'm trying your suggestion now :)

Comment: @Jatt make sure you wrap the code within the Threads `run()` method in a `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block, because updating `JLabel` position it simply from `Thread` is against Swing best practices. Alternatively have a look at a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) which will run on EDT.

Comment: @Dan I would mention something about EDT to OP as you gave him the advice to use a Thread to move Swing component which thus takes it off EDT unless I have misunderstood your solution. +1 though for `JPanel` solution usually is better than moving a `JLabel` around (especially for gaming purposes)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Forgot to mention about the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

You should better add a `JPanel` instead of the label to your layout. Choose the dimensions of the `JPanel` so that it can contain your car in every phase.

Then overwrite the `paint` method of that panel to position the image on it.

Comment: JPanel for the car, or also for the Background?

Comment: @Jatt There will be no difference. You have to use the `JPanel` as paint area which paints the car on itself. With it's own paint method.

Comment: @Jatt both of ways are correct, by unsing paintComponent or moving with JLabel, doesn't matter, depends of your decision